# GCP - Error assigning lifecycle rule to bucket using Pulumi Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pulumi

I'm fairly new with Python (I only know the basics to understand some basic scripting), and I'm trying to use Pulumi to deploy a service into GCP. What I'd like to do, is to create a bucket according to this documentation.

This is the documentation
https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/google-native/api-docs/storage/v1/bucket/

The main issue comes up while trying to assign a lifecycle policy to the bucket. Otherways, I've no problem in creating the bucket without it, but, I want it to have it.

This is the example from Pulumi's doc

```
@overload
def Bucket(resource_name: str,
           opts: Optional[ResourceOptions] = None,
           acl: Optional[Sequence[BucketAccessControlArgs]] = None,
           billing: Optional[BucketBillingArgs] = None,
           cors: Optional[Sequence[BucketCorsItemArgs]] = None,
           custom_placement_config: Optional[BucketCustomPlacementConfigArgs] = None,
           default_event_based_hold: Optional[bool] = None,
           default_object_acl: Optional[Sequence[ObjectAccessControlArgs]] = None,
           encryption: Optional[BucketEncryptionArgs] = None,
           etag: Optional[str] = None,
           iam_configuration: Optional[BucketIamConfigurationArgs] = None,
           id: Optional[str] = None,
           kind: Optional[str] = None,
           labels: Optional[Mapping[str, str]] = None,
           lifecycle: Optional[BucketLifecycleArgs] = None,
           location: Optional[str] = None,
           location_type: Optional[str] = None,
           logging: Optional[BucketLoggingArgs] = None,
           metageneration: Optional[str] = None,
           name: Optional[str] = None,
           owner: Optional[BucketOwnerArgs] = None,
           predefined_acl: Optional[str] = None,
           predefined_default_object_acl: Optional[str] = None,
           project: Optional[str] = None,
           project_number: Optional[str] = None,
           projection: Optional[str] = None,
           provisional_user_project: Optional[str] = None,
           retention_policy: Optional[BucketRetentionPolicyArgs] = None,
           rpo: Optional[str] = None,
           satisfies_pzs: Optional[bool] = None,
           self_link: Optional[str] = None,
           storage_class: Optional[str] = None,
           time_created: Optional[str] = None,
           updated: Optional[str] = None,
           user_project: Optional[str] = None,
           versioning: Optional[BucketVersioningArgs] = None,
           website: Optional[BucketWebsiteArgs] = None)
@overload
def Bucket(resource_name: str,
           args: Optional[BucketArgs] = None,
           opts: Optional[ResourceOptions] = None)
```

This is my code

```
"""A Google Cloud Python Pulumi program"""
import pulumi
from pulumi_google_native.storage import v1 as storage

action1=storage.BucketLifecycleRuleItemActionArgs(storage_class='coldline', type='SetStorageClass')
condition1=storage.BucketLifecycleRuleItemConditionArgs(age=30, matches_storage_class='nearline')
myrule=storage.BucketLifecycleRuleItemArgs(action=action1, condition=condition1)
mycustomlifecycle=storage.outputs.BucketLifecycleResponse(rule=myrule)

bucket2 = storage.Bucket(resource_name='my-bucket', location='US-EAST1', location_type='region', storage_class='standard', lifecycle=mycustomlifecycle)

# Export the bucket self-link
pulumi.export('bucketSelfLink', bucket.self_link)
```

And, when I execute the following command to see how it will work

`pulumi preview`

```
    raise AssertionError((f"Unexpected type; expected a value of type `{typ}`"
AssertionError: Unexpected type; expected a value of type `typing.Sequence[pulumi_google_native.storage.v1.output.BucketLifecycleRuleItemResponse]` but got a value of type `<class `dict`>` at resource `my-bucket2`, property `lifecycle.rule`: {`action`: {`storageClass`: `Coldline`, `type`: `SetStorageClass`}, `condition`: {`age`: `30.0`, `matchesStorageClass`: `nearline`}}
```

I'm quite sure that I'm not passing properly the expected property for the lifecyle rule, the thing is, that I'm not getting how to pass it (as I don't know much about Python).
I've been trying to pass those values in different ways (instead of a string, just putting all into one line) but I'm getting nowhere.

I'll appreciate any guidance in how to put on track this error.

**SOLUTION:**
Ok, apparently all I had to do was asking in stackoverflow to fix it.
I manage to crack it.
This is what I've changed

```
mycustomlifecycle=storage.outputs.BucketLifecycleResponse(rule=[myrule])
```

If I'm not wrong, what was happening was that I was passing a string or dict value to a property expecting a sequence. Adding the [] turned into a sequence, and therefore the code now works.

Either way, if someone will care to explain WHY, it will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to see you managed to get this figured out. I'll answer your question as to why.

Every Pulumi resource has a bunch of properties. Those properties need to have a specific *type* assigned to them. This helps you write more effective infrastructure code by reducing the feedback loop. Your IDE (if you're using one) will tell you that you've passed a property to a resource and validate if it meets the requirements.

In this particular example, you're building a BucketLifeCycleResponse, and the upstream Google Cloud API allows you specify more than one of these when creating your bucket. You can see this in the Pulumi API docs:

> BucketLifecycleResponse **rule**: This property is required.BucketLifecycleRuleItemResponse[]

Make note of the `[]` at the end there - this is telling you that this property can be specified multiple times.

In your original attempt, you didn't specify the set, and therefore your pulumi program didn't meet the requirements. Once you added the `[]` you satisfied the API requirements, and now it works!